# What's wrong with my HTML/jQuery toggle script?

Tags: jquery, html, fireworks

I have this function in a script in the header (generated by Fireworks, it works):

```
function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; 
document.MM_sr=new Array;
   for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)  
      if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){
         document.MM_sr[j++]=x; 
         if(!x.oSrc) 
            x.oSrc=x.src; 
            x.src=a[i+2];
      }
}
```

Then I have a table with a bunch of td and trs, including this one:

```
   <td rowspan="2"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="MM_swapImage('slice1_s1','','images/slice1_s2.jpg',1);"><img name="slice1_s1" src="images/slice1_s1.jpg" width="146" height="87" border="0" id="slice1_s1" alt="" /></a></td>
```

Then, after the table ends, I put this script:

```
<script>
$("img").toggle(function(){
   $(this).MM_swapImage('slice1_s1', '', 'slice1_s2.jpg', 1); 
}, function(){
   $(this).MM_swapImage('slice1_s1', '', 'slice1_s1.jpg', 1); 
});
</script>
```

The tables and all are just the way Adobe Fireworks slices stuff up for the web, so that's all generated as well.

Here's what I want to happen: When the picture is clicked, I want it to change color (which is a second image I have ready, slice1_s2.jpg). When it is clicked again, I want it to go back to original. When I test this, nothing happens. Any suggestions?

Comment: `$(this).MM_swapImage()` will not work because `MM_swapImage()` is not a jQuery method. Maybe it works if you just remove `$(this).` .

Comment: Yeah, you'll probably want to make it a jquery function, i.e., 
    jQuery.fn.MM_swapImage = function(){
        ...
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Felix Kling's comment, I believe, is correct.  I can't say for sure since I can't see all the code that you're using - but it makes sense.  I took your code and mocked up a local version.  I got an error where `$(this).MM_swapImage` was called, saying the object wasn't defined.  Once I removed `$(this).`, I got a different error in `MM_swapImage` (because I don't have all the code), but this indicates the root of your problem.

But a question I have is why not just use jQuery's `toggle` method to swap out the image?  You could just do this:

```
$("img").toggle(function(){
    $(this).attr("src", "slice1_s2.jpg");
}, function(){
    $(this).attr("src", "slice1_s1.jpg");
});
```

Not sure if you have to use MM_swapImage or not.

Felix Kling should get the correct answer.  I just wanted to throw in using `toggle` to swap your image.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This does what I want it to do. I'm gonna give you the correct answer, but I have another quick question...let's say I have more than one "img" though, how can I access one specific img? With what you have, every image I click does goes from the blue box and back to the gray box. (sorry I didn't specify the first time)

Comment: You'll have to limit your selector, in that case.  Maybe you can apply a class to only those `<img>` elements that you want to toggle (e.g. `<img id='blah' class='toggleMarker' src='...'/>`) and then your selector would look for those img's with that class (e.g. `$("img.toggleMarker").toggle(...)`).  This way, you can have img's throughout your page but only the ones with the marker class will have the toggle behavior.  Hopefully this helps.  Let me know if there are other questions.

Comment: Yes. thank you, it works great! If you're not already jesus, i'm nominating you for the next election.

Comment: LOL!!  It's an honor just to be nominated.  :)  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$("img").toggle(function(){
   $(this).MM_swapImage('slice1_s1', '', 'images/slice1_s2.jpg', 1); 
}, function(){
   $(this).MM_swapImage('slice1_s1', '', 'images/slice1_s1.jpg', 1); 
});
</script>
```

Did you try to put your path or the image?  **"images/"**

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that the OnClick event attached to your A tag will take precedence over your later script; I don't think that your toggle() will ever fire based on this.  Try removing the OnClick event and see if that doesn't do it.